# How to draw an outline for SCNNode

Tags: swift, arkit

I want to add an outline to the SCNnode in ARKIT to indicate its selection when the user taps on it. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take a look at this post:
[Is there a way to add an outline in scene kit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665700/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-outline-in-scene-kit)

There is also an example on GitHub: [GitHub Outline Example](https://github.com/laanlabs/SCNTechniqueGlow)